# A new way to keep track of global variables inside a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python

So I came across a recursive solution to a problem that keeps track of a global variable differently than I've seen before. I am aware of two ways:

One being by using the **global** keyword:

```
count = 0
def global_rec(counter):
  global count
  count += 1

  # do stuff

print(count)
```

And another using **default variables**:

```
def variable_recursive(counter, count=0):
  count += 1
  if counter <= 0:
    return count
  return variable_recursive(counter-1, count)
```

***The new way***:

```
#driver function
def driver(counter):
  #recursive function being called here
  rec_utility.result = 0  <---initializing

  rec_utility(counter)  <--- calling the recursive function
  print(rec_utility.result)

def rec_utility(counter):
  if counter <= 0:
    return
  rec_utility.result += 1   <---- 'what is happening here'
  rec_utility(counter-1)
```

I find this way a lot simpler, as in default variable method we have to return the variables we want to keep a track of and the code get really messy really fast. Can someone please explain why passing a variable joint to a function, like an object property works? I understand that python functions are nothing but objects, but is this a hacky way of keeping track of the variables or is it common practice? If so why do we have so many ways to achieve the same task? Thanks!

Comment: Sure hope no one rebinds the name `rec_utility` in your last example ...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as magical as you might think.  It might be poor practice.

`rec_utility` is just a variable in your namespace which happens to be a function.  `dir()` will show it listed when it is in scope.  As an object it can have new fields set.   `dir(rec_utility)` will show these new fields, along with `__code__` and others.

Like any object, you can set a new field value, as you are doing in your code.  There is only one `rec_utility` function, even though you call it recursively, so its the same field when you initialize it and when you modify it.

Once you understand it, you can decide if it is a good idea.  It might be less confusing or error prone to use a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, this question has nothing to do with recursive functions.  Suppose a function requires an item of information to operate correctly, then do you:

1. provide it via a global; or
2. pass it in as a parameter; or
3. set it as a function attribute prior to calling it.

In the final case, it’s worth considering that it is not entirely robust:

```
def f():
    # f is not this function!!
    return f.x + 1

f.x = 100

for f in range(10): pass
```

Generally, we would consider the second option the best one. There’s nothing special really about its recursive nature, other than the need to provide state, which is information, to the next invocation.